# Python: Select and move file based on criteria in a directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, file-io, shutil

I have about 10 minutes of video and just extracted into every frame so I have more than 100,000 of images in my folder and renamed them from 1 to 100,000. Now I want to select 1 of every 30 from 1 to 100,000 images and move them to another folder. For example : 1, 31,61,91,121,151,181 and so on.

This is my code so far:

```
import os
import shutil

PATH = './Folder1/'
DEST = './Folder2/'

file = 1

for file in os.listdir(PATH):
    file = file + 30
    shutil.copyfile(PATH, DEST)
```

But it gave me following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-b08091703697> in <module>
      9 # Get a list of files in the current working directory
     10 for file in os.listdir(PATH):
---> 11     file = file + 30
     12     shutil.copyfile(PATH, DEST)

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Your error said that you need to convert int to str before adding them together. You can use

```
file = file + str(30)
```

then improve your original code later on.

Or you can use my idea below.

```
for idx in range(1, 100000, 30):
   shutil.copyfile(PATH + str(idx), DEST)
```

Comment: Best answer since it got to the root of the question.

Comment: Thanks for quick respond. I just tried all the answers but it says PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './Folder2/'.

Comment: Following docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile
I think we could try:

   shutil.copyfile(PATH + str(idx), DEST + str(idx))

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
PATH = '/Folder1/'
DEST = './Folder2/'
l = os.listdir(PATH)
file = 1

for file in l[::30]:
    shutil.copyfile(PATH, DEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

"file" in `for file in os.listdir(PATH)` is a string, so `file = file + 30` is not valid.
you should try:

```
import os
import shutil

PATH = './Folder1/'
DEST = './Folder2/'

filenames = os.listdir(PATH)

for i in range(1, len(filenames), 30):
    shutil.copyfile(PATH + filenames[i], DEST)
```